# Merge billing address, shipping address and shipping method on onepage

Tags: shipping-methods, shipping-address, onepage-checkout

I managed to join the file:

```
\ template \ checkout \ onepage \ shipping.phtml
```

with:

```
\ template \ persistent \ checkout \ onepage \ billing.phtml
```

But I must also add the file:

```
\ template \ checkout \ onepage \ shipping_method.phtml
```

Needed to load the method shipping using ajax. But I'm not sure where to start, can someone show me any solution or tip. I am trying to change the Controllers and Blocks too.

I made several changes I dont want to install any module of checkout.

Thanks in advance.

==================================

**EDIT 1:**

Please see (on line 442):
http://pastebin.com/aCJXGjFr

It is the file:

```
\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
```

And, I tried to move the folder:

```
\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\
```

To:

```
\template\persistent\onepage\shipping_method\
```

Now I am trying to edit the Controllers/Blocks.. But I dont know how refresh the Shipping Method.

==================================

**EDIT 2:**

I changed this file:

```
app\design\frontend\default\my_theme\layout\persistent.xml
```

I changed this:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
```

To this:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
```

Now I can load Shipping Method, but I need to reload when the client changes the postal code with ajax. Can someone help me?

Comment: Since this will affect multiple files, is there a way you can commit your code so we can see what is currently happening?

Comment: Please see edit 1

Comment: What controllers and blocks are you editing? Are you creating your own extension or editing core code?

Comment: Editing core... I am changing on persistent folder (on local folder).

Comment: I think before anyone will help you, you need to make the proper rewrites. You will experience a lot more grief and trouble down the road if you make core rewrites. Take a look at this article: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: Please see edit 2